# check the bounds changes in google map by touch event, in real time

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want check the bounds changes in google map by Touch event.
Specifically, i want make some system, if i touch the screen displaying google map, 
and change the bounds, send something can specify new map to server. To body out this
system, At first time, I used bound_changed event. like below

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', (function () {
    var bar=map.getCenter()
    socket.emit('center_spe', bar);
}));
```

it works in my laptop! if i drag the map by my mouse, google map send variable in real time.
but if i use the touch device, google map send "bar" just when my the touching is over.

of course i checked event list in google map developer's reference and 
i realize there is no event about touch event. like touchmove, touchstart, etc.
(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ko#Map)

is there magic can make me check the bound-changes in real time when i using the touch-device? like below.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,"touchmove",function(event) { 
    var bar=event.latLng;
    socket.emit('message', bar);
});
```

(of course there is no touch event in google map event, above code doesn't work)

Comment: Have you tried `dragstart`? Untested, but you might give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Maps V3 API Events for google.maps.Map Demo](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html), if you check on a touch device you can see that once you start dragging the map, *drag* and *dragstart* events get fired. *drag* event repeatedly gets fired while you drag the map. Once you stop dragging and remove you finger from the screen both *bounds_changed* and *dragend* events get fired. So for your purpose you can easily use *dragend* event.
Here's an example on how to use it:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function(){
    console.log('drag ended');
});
```

Where *map* is your map element.
If you consider using both *bounds_changed* and *dragend* events, since there is no built-in method to apply a listener for multiple events and yet you don't want to define the callback-function twice, you can do this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'bounds_changed', function(e){ console.log('bound changed');} );
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'dragend', function(){ google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'bounds_changed');} );
```

On my PC *bounds_changed* repeatedly gets fired while I drag the map (like *drag* event) , but on my mobile *bounds_changed* gets fired once I stop dragging the map and I remove my finger from the screen. On the other hand *dragend* event behaves the same both on my PC and Mobile. I personally would use the first method (*dragend* event) *for the purpose you mentioned*.

Comment: This is an excellent description of the different behaviour for bounds_changed on desktop vs mobile.  The same behaviour applies to center_changed.  You can confirm the different behaviour by changing the device type in your browser's developer tools and reloading the page.  Agree with your advice about using the drag events instead to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: One caveat with listening to drag events and then grabbing the camera position: getCenter() and getBounds() will not update to reflect the new camera position until the drag has ended.